# Erlang: ripemd160 not supported

Tags: cryptography, erlang

my erlang version is `24` and it does not support ripemd160 hash algorithm and i don't know why. the erlang crytpo document says it is a supported algorithm.

```
crypto:start(),
B = crypto:hash(ripemd160, H).
```

it gives me this error:

```
** exception error: notsup
     in function  crypto:notsup_to_error/1 (crypto.erl, line 2147)
```

i searched online for this and could not found the solution and tried couple of method but could not solve it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Erlang version exactly? And are you using OpenSSL 3? The [release notes](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/notes#crypto-5.0.5) mention that ripemd160 was disabled in 24.2 when compiled with OpenSSL 3.0, and reenabled in 24.3.

Comment: @legoscia 
coding: utf-8
[{release,"Erlang/OTP","24","12.2.1",
          [{kernel,"8.2","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/kernel-8.2"},
           {stdlib,"3.17","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/stdlib-3.17"},
           {sasl,"4.1.1","/usr/lib/erlang/lib/sasl-4.1.1"}],
          permanent}].

Comment: Why is this tagged with `elixir`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Erlang installation seems to match release 24.2.1, and thus is affected by this part of [the crypto release notes](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/notes#crypto-5.0.5):

> The hash algorithms `md4` and `ripemd160` are disabled temporarily when compiled with OpenSSL 3.0.

Support for these algorithms was reinstated in release 24.3.

---

Note that support for OpenSSL 3 (as opposed to 1.1.1 and earlier versions) was considered experimental for all Erlang 24 releases. Release 25.1 was the first one that [said](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/notes#crypto-5.1.2):

> Crypto is now considered to be usable with the OpenSSL 3.0 cryptolib for production code.
>
> ENGINE and FIPS are not yet fully functional.

Comment: i unistalled current version and install it again and it's working. it's erlang 25.3 now,
thank you, last question : why they disabled it?

Comment: That's a good question. It was disabled in [this commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/e75424b85fbb92718e363937d82247ee60225daa), but the commit message doesn't explain why that was done...